# Looking for a better way to initialize an Eigen3 Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen3

I've got a situation where I derive an Eigen3 matrix with complex elements from one with double elements.  At the moment I just loop over the rows and columns and fill in the entries one by one.  I was wondering if anyone knew of any approach along the lines of:

```
 complexMatrix = doubleMatrix.unaryExpr(transform)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an operator in Eigen for that called [cast](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a660200abaf1fc4b888330a37d6132b76). The declaration looks scary because of the template stuff, but usage is pretty simple.

I think this should work

```
complexMatrix = doubleMatrix.cast< std::complex<double> >();
```

Edit, umm ok... there is a way to do this. There is an example in the documentation: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7

However I believe, that to get proper type you need to combine `cast` and functor.

```
complexMatrix = doubleMatrix.cast< std::complex<double> >().unaryExpr( FUNCTOR );
```

Of course functor is expected to be designed to work with complex `Scalar` type. You can also use `fnc_ptr` wrapper with a plain function  as shown in the example.

Note: It might be possible to skip `cast` when using functor class that accepts double and returns complex, but I didn't manage to do it off the bat. It would be tricky. I also don't think it is necessary becasue `cast` probably does not introduce any real overhead.

**Edit: Working example.**

It does introduce a little bit of overhead from converting `x` from `double` to `complex` back and forth 2 times, but i expect it to be negligible compared to the actual functor body.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

std::complex<double> functor(double x){
  //complicated stuff
  return std::complex<double> (x, -2*x) ;
}

std::complex<double> wrapper(std::complex<double> x)
{
    //nothing is lost here, as we expect x to have only real part 
    //from being upcasted from the original matrix
    double xReal = x.real();
    return functor(xReal);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  Matrix4d m1 = Matrix4d::Random();
  cout << m1 << endl << "becomes: " << endl 
       << m1.cast< std::complex<double> >().unaryExpr(ptr_fun(wrapper)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting, but I do need the 'transform' operation - think of it as a functor that takes a double argument and returns a complex result.

Comment: @user888379 Edited answer with an idea and examples in he documentation that should help to do it.

Comment: I do have the option of implementing my functor so that it takes a complex argument, so it looks like I can eliminate the additional conversion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, real numbers are subset of complex, so this is natural. Operations on complex numbers are more expensive than on real types. So maybe its not worth it. The conversion is probably cheaper than few multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

unaryExpr can deduce the return type from the functor, so one can do:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
std::complex<double> functor(double x){
  return std::complex<double> (-x, x) ;
}
int main(int, char**)
{
  Eigen::Matrix3d m1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix3cd m2 = m1.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(functor));
}
```

and with a functor class:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
struct Functor {
  typedef std::complex<double> result_type;
  std::complex<double> operator()(double x) const {
    return std::complex<double> (-x, x) ;
  }
};
int main(int, char**)
{
  Eigen::Matrix3d m1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix3cd m2 = m1.unaryExpr(Functor());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need something more like Matrix3cd = m1.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(transform)); which won't compile as it stands.

Comment: I've updated the example to make self contained. It works for me.

Comment: Interesting - I thought I had tried that approach. I'll definitely revisit it. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that the crucial difference in my set-up is that I'm using a function object (because I need some additional state for the computation).  The compiler complains that it needs the cast method.  I am able to replicate your result if I use a simple function and wrap it with std::ptr_fun.  Good to know.

Comment: your functor must be STL compliant, that is, it must define a `result_type` typedef to the returned type if it is not trivial. std::ptr_fun does that for you when using free functions.

Comment: My functor inherits from std::unary_functor, but I had managed to swap the template parameters. Your mention of result_type was what led me to eventually realize what the problem was, and fix it.  Everything is working cleanly now - no cast needed anymore.